# convert indices into corresponding pandas dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a matrix of indices, I'd like to get the same matrix filled with values taken from pandas dataframe predefined column corresponding to the index on a given position.

For example, index matrix

```
[[0 1 2]
 [1 0 2]
 [2 1 3]
 [3 4 2]]
```

pd.DataFrame["id"]:

```
100
200
300
400
500
600
700
800
900
```

Expected result:

```
 [[100 200 300]
  [200 100 300]
  [300 100 400]
  [400 500 300]]
```

Appears

```
t_ind = [ td[(td.index.isin(ind[:,0]))]["id"].values,
          td[(td.index.isin(ind[:,1]))]["id"].values,
          td[(td.index.isin(ind[:,2]))]["id"].values ]
```

breaks the structure and return only unique values, while the full list expected

Any idea how to make the conversion properly?

NB: The data set is huge, going element by element is non-acceptable, the conversion should be done in a single operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make your index array an `ndarray`, you can use it to index into another `ndarray`, which we can get from your Series using `.values`:

```
>>> ix
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [2, 1, 3],
       [3, 4, 2]])
>>> df["id"].values[ix]
array([[100, 200, 300],
       [200, 100, 300],
       [300, 200, 400],
       [400, 500, 300]], dtype=int64)
```

Alternatively, if your `ix` is a frame, you could call `replace`:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(ix).replace(df["id"])
     0    1    2
0  100  200  300
1  200  100  300
2  300  200  400
3  400  500  300
```

I suspect the purely numpy approach would be much faster, but that's easy to measure.

Comment: thanks @DSM, my ix is ndarray and an array (not a frame) is what I need, the 1st variant works just fine

Answer (score 0):

## Setup

`i_s` is a list of list.  This works equally well if it were a numpy array.

```
i_s = [[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [2, 1, 3],
       [3, 4, 2]]

s = pd.DataFrame([100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900])
```

`s` does not have to be a `DataFrame`.  I made it so to be consistent with the OP's question.

## Solution

```
pd.DataFrame([[s.iloc[i, 0] for i in i_s[j]] for j in range(len(i_s))])

     0    1    2
0  100  200  300
1  200  100  300
2  300  200  400
3  400  500  300
```